# Looking for a JSON library with relaxed syntax

Tags: java, json

The JSON syntax is very simple but also very strict with names and strings. So i am looking for a JSON library that allows some relaxed syntax for strings.

> Any token not startng with
>   [0-9],:[]{}" and not is *true*, *false*
>   or *null* is a valid name/string.

So that this 2 JSON are equivalent

```
{
  "name":"Eric",
  "addr":"461, Ocean Boulevard"
}

{
  name:Eric,
  addr:"461, Ocean Boulevard"
}
```

**Update**
I googled again and found [RSON](http://code.google.com/p/rson/wiki/Manual) for Python, something similar for Java ?

Comment: I think it is incorrect to refer to both of those as JSON, you want a JSON like syntax, but if it doesn't conform to the JSON spec it isn't JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is likely to write a small converter class, which can translate to and from your "quasi-JSON".  Should take less than an hour, and then you're free to use whatever standard library you please.

**Update:**  Since you've found a Python script that does what you want, and since that "RSON" code is pretty straightforward and self-contained in a single file... why not simply embed it your Java app using the http://www.jython.org/ library?

Comment: Less than 1 hour, i doubt. To do it well, i have to write a JSON parser anyway ...

Comment: It doesn't have to understand full-blown "JSON"... it only has to understand "strings that are missing their double-quotes".  Perhaps more than an hour to thoroughly test and make it bullet-proof, but it's still far less ambitious that a complete JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

At least [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) allows it for keys. No one comes to mind which does the same for values, but it's invalid in real JavaScript anyway.